# Negative margin does not pull up floated siblings in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-float, margins

I have a box which contains a heading and two other boxes. The heading has negative margin top so that it renders outside the box. In every browser except Firefox the heading correctly pulls up its sibling boxes, but in Firefox the boxes stay in place.

If I remove the float from the boxes however they *do* move up. Is there a fix for this other than giving the boxes negative margin-top as well?

```css
div {
  background: red;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin-top: 8rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}

div div {
  background: green;
  margin: 0 0 2rem;
  width: 45%;
  float: left; /* Remove this and float: right below and it works in FF */
}

div div + div {
  float: right;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: -8rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h2>
Hello
</h2>
<div>
These boxes also render outside the red one.
</div>
<div>
In every browser except Firefox.
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can wrap the floated boxes in a non-floated container.**
(note: I gave each div its own class just to make it more clear exactly which styles were applying to which div.)

```css
.d1 {background:red; padding:2rem; margin-top:8rem; box-sizing:border-box;}
.d1:after {display:table; content:""; clear:both;}
.d3 {float:left; background:green; padding:2rem; box-sizing:border-box; width:45%;}
.d3 + .d3 {float:right;}
h2 {margin-top:-8rem;}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    <div class="d2">
        <div class="d3">These boxes render outside the red one.</div>
        <div class="d3">In every browser.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of adding an extra div to my code, but this clearly works so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First I further simplified into the *minimal* example below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  background: red;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin-top: 8rem;
}
.wrapper > div {
  background: green;
  padding: 2rem;
  float:left;
}
.wrapper:after{
  content: '';
  clear:both;
  display: table;
}
h2 {
  margin-top: -8rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>Hello</h2>
  <div>These boxes also render outside the red one.</div>
</div>
```

**Why this happens?**

1. First try removing the `padding` from `wrapper` and see that now [*margin collapsing*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) will come into play and shows same behavior even in Firefox. (The `padding: 2rem` for `wrapper` prevents the margin of `h2` collapsing with `wrapper`). So clearly *margin collpasing* has no role here.

   ```css
       * {
         box-sizing: border-box;
       }
       body {
         margin: 0;
       }
       .wrapper {
         background: red;
         margin-top: 8rem;
       }
       .wrapper > div {
         background: green;
         padding: 2rem;
         float:left;
       }
       .wrapper:after{
         content: '';
         clear:both;
         display: table;
       }
       h2 {
         margin-top: -8rem;
       }
   ```

   ```html
       <div class="wrapper">
         <h2>Hello</h2>
         <div>These boxes also render outside the red one.</div>
       </div>
   ```
2. Now try toggling `float: left` for the div inside `wrapper` and you can see that *Floated* containers have issues with *negative margins* (in Firefox).

   ```css
       * {
         box-sizing: border-box;
       }
       body {
         margin: 0;
       }
       .wrapper {
         background: red;
         padding: 2rem;
         margin-top: 8rem;
       }
       .wrapper > div {
         background: green;
         padding: 2rem;
       }
       .wrapper:after{
         content: '';
         clear:both;
         display: table;
       }
       h2 {
         margin-top: -8rem;
       }
   ```

   ```html
       <div class="wrapper">
         <h2>Hello</h2>
         <div>These boxes also render outside the red one.</div>
       </div>
   ```

**So this is a bug?**

The docs just has this to say:

> Negative values for margin properties are allowed, but there may be
>   implementation-specific limits.(Source: [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties))

and it looks like Firefox has an old bug raised for it and still open I guess - see [***`this Bugzilla link`***](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=441978).

**Solution**

Don't keep *floated* siblings for containers that have negative margins:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  background: red;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin-top: 8rem;
}
.wrapper > .float-wrap > div {
  background: green;
  padding: 2rem;
  float:left;
}
.wrapper > .float-wrap:after{
  content: '';
  clear:both;
  display: table;
}
h2 {
  margin-top: -8rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>Hello</h2>
  <div class="float-wrap">
    <div>These boxes also render outside the red one.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So here's the solution for your code wrapping the *floated container*:

```css
div {
  background: red;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin-top: 8rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
div > div > div {
  background: green;
  margin: 0 0 2rem;
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
}
div > div > div + div {
  float: right;
}
h2 {
  margin-top: -8rem;
}
div > h2 + div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Hello</h2>
  <div>
    <div>
      These boxes also render outside the red one.
    </div>
    <div>
      In every browser except Firefox.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's essentially the same solution as andi provided and since he was an hour before you I feel I need to give him the credit for it. I'll give you a +1 for a really thorough answer though.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that this could be a bug in every browser except Firefox.

[The Working Draft Collapsing Margin Spec states:](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#collapsing-margins)

> - **Margins of a floated box do not collapse with any other margins.**
> - If a box is collapsed through and it **has clearance applied** to one of the collapsed margins, then those margins **do not collapse** with certain of the parent's margins: If clearance is applied to, respectively, the top, right or left margin, then those margins do not collapse with the parent's bottom, left or right margin, respectively.

It appears that most browsers, besides Firefox, are incorrectly allowing the floated div margins to collapse. However, by setting a `clear` property to the `div div` css will cause the floats to remain in their container (See snippet below). This behavior is more inline with what the spec sates.

[The Recommendation for positioning of floats](http://A%20floating%20box's%20outer%20top%20may%20not%20be%20higher%20than%20the%20top%20of%20its%20containing%20block.) also leads me to believe that what you are seeing in other browsers may not be the desired result. The Spec recommendation seems to indicate that floated items should always be positioned within their parent container unless specifically stated otherwise.

> A floating box's outer top may not be higher than the top of its containing block.

---

**Demo to show that adding clearing to the floats will keep them contained in their parent**

```css
div {
  background: red;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin-top: 8rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}

div div {
  background: green;
  margin: 0 0 2rem;
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  clear:right; // Adding this causes the floats to stay in their container
}

div div + div {
  float: right;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: -8rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h2>
Hello
</h2>
<div>
These boxes also render outside the red one.
</div>
<div>
In every browser except Firefox.
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps you're right about that. I have to say I prefer the non-Firefox way of handling this though.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how block structure is computed in a browser. I solved it by replacing `margin-top` with `top` and `position` property

```
div {
  background: red;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin-top: 8rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}

div div {
  position: relative;
  top: -12rem;
  background: green;
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  /* Remove this and float: right below and it works in FF */
}

div div + div {
  float: right;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: -8rem;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nobalmohan/6sjhy1q3/

I am sure, there are other ways to solve it too.

Comment: "It depends on how block structure is computed in a browser" what does that mean? :P Seems like a Firefox bug to me. I'd prefer _not_ to give every nested div margin-top as well as I stated in my question, but I may fall back on that solution if there's no bug fix available.

Comment: Also, the problem with using `position: relative` as opposed to negative margin is that the container box is still as tall as it was before the elements moved up. I don't want that.